# TypeError: html.window.navigator.geolocation[$watchPosition] is not a function

Tags: angular-dart

I am getting error

TypeError: html.window.navigator.geolocation[$watchPosition] is not a function

during execution of below function in one of the component. Do I need to do any setup before calling methods in window.navigator.geolocation?

```
@override
void ngOnInit() {
  if (window.navigator.geolocation != null) {
    //try {
    window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(enableHighAccuracy: true).listen(
        (position) => userPosition = position,
        onError: (Error er) {});
    //} catch (e) {
    //}
  }
}
```

Comment: This issue has been reported and someone posted a polyfill you can use as is:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32592#issuecomment-374376518